# Custom Exception in php extension

Tags: php, zend-framework, php-extension

I'm writing php extension and am able to throw exceptions to userspace implementations through a call to:

```
zend_throw_exception(...);
```

and everything works fine. I would like to know how I can create my custom exception that I will want to throw to userspace implementations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have some code so far?

Comment: Yeah I have some code and works with zend_throw_exception(....), exception is thrown to userspace implementation. Now I want a custom one other than spl_ce_RuntimeException, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Extend PHP's Exception class to make custom exceptions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php

There is also a Zend_Exception class which acts as a catch-all for any exception in the Zend framework which may be of some use to you.

Comment: The question is asking how to throw a custom exception from within a PHP extension - i.e. C code - not PHP.